# TinyMCE rewrites query string on image src

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I'm using Glide package (https://glide.thephpleague.com) to manipulate images based on query string params. Lets say I have `/some/large/image.jpg` , it can be easily scaled down like this `/some/large/image.jpg?w=300&h=200`

I want these query params to be applied automaticly in TinyMCE (simlplified example)

```
tinymce.init({
  ...
  convert_urls: false,
  setup: (editor) => {
    editor.on('ObjectResized', (e) => {
      let src = e.target.src.replace(/\?.+/, '');
      let resizedSrc = `${src}?w=${e.width}&h=${e.height}`;
      e.target.src = resizedSrc;
      e.target.alt = resizedSrc; // to prove it works
      console.log(e.target); 
    });
  }
})
```

but TinyMCE trims the query string part in `src`. The console logged `e` still has `src` and `alt` set as I want it, but if I display TinyMCE generated source `src` is missing the query string, `alt` stays intact.

https://codepen.io/vitnasinec/pen/YzyEBZQ

Any idea how to prevent TinyMCE (5.2.2) rewriting my `src`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `editor.dom.setAttrib` in the TinyMCE DOMUtils API:

```
editor.dom.setAttrib(e.target, 'src', resizedSrc);
editor.dom.setAttrib(e.target, 'alt', resizedSrc);
```

See this [TinyMCE Fiddle](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Ihhaab) for a working example.